# Data Deletion Request Callback for Facebook Login on Flutter Web

Tags: firebase, flutter, facebook

I am developing a Flutter web app using Firebase as backend. While trying to enable Facebook login, I found the following requirement:

> Apps that access user data must provide a way for users to request that their data be deleted. Your app can satisfy this requirement in one of two ways:
>
> - Implement a Data Deletion Request Callback.
> - Provide a URL with explicit instructions for app users on how to delete their data by way of a third-party website or tool. The third-party website may be the relevant section in the application's Privacy Policy.

Implementing a data deletion request call back can be harder, because I don't have a regular backend, I am using Firebase.

I think the second option it is better, however it is not completely clear to me what they mean by “delete their data by way of a third-party website or tool”. Is it possible to have an URL in the app with a “delete account button” and give the corresponding instructions in the URL?

How should I fulfill these requirements?

Is there an efficient way to fulfill them?

Comment: Yes, a URL with a button for them to have their account and the belonging data removed from your system, should be sufficient.